# How to clear data in the paging file in windows when close crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, out-of-memory

I have crystal report on window form C# to display multi image. I know that crystal report use the "Paging File" of Windows to swap data. I open and close report several times (about 3 times) then i get message "Memory full" when the Physical Memory was free. I think that need to clear data in the paging file when close the report(I have use GC.Collect(), set report to null and dispose report but does not solve the problem)
Please help me how to clear data in the paging file using c# when i close crystal report ?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to close de report and then dispose it.

```
MyReport.Close();
MyReport.Dispose();
```

also dispose the viewer

```
MyCrystalReportViewer.Dispose();
```